# How to get browser window front while running the test using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently running my selenium webdriver tests in 2 browsers (`studentdriver` and `tutordriver`)

```
studentdriver = new ChromeDriver();# opening student in chrome browser
tutordriver = new FrefoxDriver();#opening tutor with firefox browser
```

and I'm student browser first and then `tutorbrowser` soth that student browser will be behind and tutorbrowser will be on front side. when script running with `studentbrowser`, it will automatically comes fron and tutorbrowser will be back side but when script start running using tutorbrowser it is not coming front side and it is creating some problem in between.

I need a solution to get `tutorbrowser` front when script start running on `tutorbrowser`.

Note: I should not close `studentbrowser` because I'm closing both the browsers in `@After`

Comment: Not sure if a browser is behind another it will actually cause issues. Once you start performing operations it should work.

Answer (score 1):

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");

try this with each driver.

Comment: +1 This worked very well and was the ONLY solution that worked for me without having to query all Windows processes and find the window through that [nasty] way!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, this is an OS problem. It's up to the window manager to handle the ovelapping, tiling, organisation of the windows, which you can't control directly from your code.

The best bet you'll have is to launch a `Sikuli` Robot with which you'll be able to bring back the correct window. It's a bit of work, though, to include in your tests, but it can be used from Java with no problem

See the beast at http://www.sikuli.org